# Why my IntelliJ never enters the Debugging Mode?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Whenever I click the Debugging button in IntelliJ it just start like the normal Run mode and gives me the following message:

"Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64136', transport: 'socket'"

"null" => my program execution results

"Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:64136', transport: 'socket'"

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJy4c.png)

Comment: Did you set any breakpoints? Was there any reason for the debugger to do anything?

Comment: Definitely I did

Comment: One Note: the "Conntected..." and "Disconnected ..." were not appearing to me previously

Comment: Do you use Debug button in the gutter of the editor, or in the toolbar (top bar)? Share your Run configuration.